# ReactJS - After component mounts need to import/rerun local javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Need to import "validation.js" file within another javascript file in reactjs once the main file render method is completes it execution

```
import './Validations';
```

should render this JS file once the main component's render method complete its execution

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is not really the way react likes to behave and probably is a mistake. if you need some extra functionality to be available in your component you could define a class, put your external logic in there and then instantiate an object from that class in your component's constructor or render method, and use whatever functionality you need in from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-loadable` library to lazy load javascript file.

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const LoadableTest = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./validations.js'),
  loading() { // you could write your spinner while the file is being loaded.
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
});

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableTest/>;
  }
}
```